# Creating UILabels with delete button

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel

For my `iOS` app, I want to create `UILabels` with a button attached to the top right. If the user presses the button, the UILabel will be deleted. Here is a visual of what I want to create :

[image: UILabel w/button on top right corner]

I know how to build the `UILabel` with the rounded corners and text but I'm a little lost on how to attach the buttons on the top right. Is the best way to create this to attach individual buttons to the labels? If I do follow this approach, wouldn't this get messy with constraints?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Yeah, it did! My bad for the late reply. Had a long week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rounded Labels**

let label = UILabel() // But can be an outlet.
label.layer.cornerRadius = label.frame.height / 2.0

(Sorry, just saw that you knew this bit. I just got excited.)

**Buttons**

The constraints shouldn't be messy. However you want to align the buttons with labels you're going to need to specify the horizontal and vertical constraints, and possibly height and width constraints.

Just in case you're unfamiliar with IB:

1. Add a vertical constraint between the label and button. Any will do for now.
2. Add a horizontal constraint between the label and button. Any will do for now.
3. Double-click the vertical constraint to refine it; set the button's Centre Y to the label's Top anchor.
4. Double-click the horizontal constraint to refine it; set the Centre X to the label's Trailing anchor.

I don't think the centre of the button is exactly on the corner, so use the Constant property to adjust.

[image: You should see something like this.]
[image]

Comment: Update - my labels are in a `horizontal stackview`, I tried following what you suggested but I'm not having any luck. Any idea how to approach adding the button if the `UILabels` are in a `stackview`?